# ASP.NET: How to Append Signature to Word Document

Tags: asp.net, ms-office

Currently I am developing a memo application for a company that each director needs to sign the word document as approved or disapprove. I have scan copy of each director as image in my DB.

The signatures and date will be appended at the bottom of the doc page.

Answer (score 0):

see here is example:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/Freddy_Khalaf/add-digital-signature-to-documents09272009104159AM/add-digital-signature-to-documents.aspx

Comment: Cool! thanks.

But,I don't have sharepoint installed on the server

"using Microsoft.SharePoint; using Microsoft.Office.Core;"

Please, need more assistance.